# API Request within another API request (Same API) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, api

I currently have made a python program, request JSON data from an API. Now here is the thing though this JSON actually contains other request Urls to get extra data from that object.

```
import requests

import json

import sys

import os

import geojson



response = requests.get("http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment", params = {"CRS": "Lambert72"})

print(response.status_code)
text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(text)

f = open("text.json", "wt")
f.write(text)

print(os.getcwd())
```

JSON from request, the other request URLs including parameters is in the detail column.

```
[
{
"gipodId": 103246,
"owner": "Eandis Leuven",
"description": ", , ZAVELSTRAAT: E Nieuw distributienet (1214m)",
"startDateTime": "2007-12-03T06:00:00",
"endDateTime": "2014-01-06T19:00:00",
"importantHindrance": false,
"coordinate": {
"coordinates": [
4.697028256276443,
50.896894135898485
],
"type": "Point",
"crs": {
"type": "name",
"properties": {
"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
}
}
},
**"detail": http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment/103246?crs=4326,
"cities": ["Leuven"]**
}
],
"latestUpdate": "2016-11-16T11:32:39.253"
}
```

The first request just gets the points (each unique with a certain id), while the second request gets the "details data" which also has polygon data and multiline.

Get Url:
[http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment/[id]](http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment/%5Bid%5D)

```
{ "comment" : null,
  "contactDetails" : { "city" : "Leuven",
      "country" : "België",
      "email" : null,
      "extraAddressInfo" : null,
      "firstName" : null,
      "lastName" : null,
      "number" : "58",
      "organisation" : "Eandis Leuven",
      "phoneNumber1" : "078/35.35.34",
      "phoneNumber2" : null,
      "postalCode" : "3012",
      "street" : "Aarschotsesteenweg"
    },
  "contractor" : null,
  "mainContractor" : null,
  "description" : ", , ZAVELSTRAAT: E Nieuw distributienet (1214m)",
  "diversions" : [
    {
    "gipodId": 1348152,
    "reference": "IOW-TERRAS-2013-01-Z",
    "description": "Horecaterras op parkeerstrook (Lierbaan 12)",
    "comment": null,
    "geometry": {
    "geometries": [
    {
        "coordinates": [[[3.212947654779088, 51.175784679668915],
        [3.2151308569159482, 51.17366647833133],
        [3.216112818368467,  51.17328051591839],
        [3.2186926906668876, 51.173044950954456],
        [3.2204789191276944, 51.173098278776514],
        [3.221602856602255,  51.173333934695286]]],
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "crs": null
        }
        ],
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
        }
    },
    "periods": [{"startDateTime": "2013-04-09T00:00:00","endDateTime": "2013-10-31T00:00:00"}],
    "recurrencePattern": null,
    "latestUpdate": "2014-01-24T10:23:08.917",
    "streets": null,
    "diversionTypes": null,
    "diversionDirection": 
        {
            "type": 0,
            "description": "Beide"
        },
    "status": "Vergund",
    "contactDetails": {
        "organisation": "Café Real",
        "lastName": "Vets",
        "firstName": "Peggy",
        "phoneNumber1": null,
        "phoneNumber2": null,
        "email": "peggy.vets@skynet.be",
        "street": "Lierbaan",
        "number": "12",
        "postalCode": "2580",
        "city": "Putte",
        "country": "België",
        "extraAddressInfo": null
        }
   "url": null,
    }
    ],
  "endDateTime" : "2014-01-06T19:00:00",
  "gipodId" : 103246,
  "hindrance" : { "description" : null,
      "direction" : null,
      "effects" : [ "Fietsers hebben doorgang",
          "Handelaars bereikbaar",
          "Verminderde doorstroming in 1 richting",
          "Voetgangers op de rijweg",
          "Voetgangers hebben doorgang"
        ],
      "important" : false,
      "locations" : [ "Voetpad" ]
    },
  "latestUpdate" : "2013-06-18T03:43:28.17",
  "location" : { "cities" : [ "Leuven" ],
      "coordinate" : { "coordinates" : [ 4.697028256276443,
              50.896894135898485
            ],
          "crs" : { "properties" : { "name" : "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" },
              "type" : "name"
            },
          "type" : "Point"
        },
      "geometry" : { "coordinates" : [ [ [ [ 4.699934331336474,
                    50.90431808607037
                  ],
                  [ 4.699948535632464,
                    50.90431829749237
                  ],
                  [ 4.699938837004092,
                    50.90458139231922
                  ],
                  [ 4.6999246328435396,
                    50.90458118062111
                  ],
                  [ 4.699934331336474,
                    50.90431808607037
                  ]
                ] ]
            ],
          "crs" : { "properties" : { "name" : "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" },
              "type" : "name"
            },
          "type" : "MultiPolygon"
        }
    },
  "owner" : "Eandis Leuven",
  "reference" : "171577",
  "startDateTime" : "2007-12-03T06:00:00",
  "state" : "In uitvoering",
  "type" : "Werken aan nutsleiding",
  "url" : "http://www.eandis.be"
}
```

Now here is the deal, this request has to be repeated for each object I get from the First API Request. And this can be over one hundred objects. So logic dictates this has to happen in a loop, though how to start is bit..troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you of functions in this case.

Your first function can simply fetch the list of the points. Your second function can simply fetch the data of details.

```
def fetch_details(url: str):
      """ Makes request call to get the data of detail """
        response = requests.get(url)
        # any other processe


def fetch_points(url: str):
       
       response = requests.get(url)
       for obj in response.json():
              fetch_details(obj.get("detail"))

api_url = "api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment"
fetch_points(api_url)
```

Comment: So to make it happen for all the points I have requested, I would have to do this right?:
apiurl = http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment
fetch_details(feth_points(apiurl))

Comment: I think just doing : api_url = api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment fetch_points(api_url) will be enough

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm this works. The print goes back. Now I go on a little further. I will be asking a different question or two later on. Where I go further from this, because  lets just say I have to modify it when I am including parameters in api_url. I think I know the answer already just add some extra strings. This answer is right for this question .Thank you once again.

Comment: No worries. I am looking forward for your questions. Keep coding keep exploring!