# Converting JSON to QGIS GeoJSON: while having multiple features and different types

Tags: python, json, geojson

Currently I have a program that request JSONS from specific API. The creators of the API have claimed this data is in GeoJSON but QGIS cannot read it.

So I want to extend my Python Script to converting the JSON to GEOJSON in a readable format to get into QGIS and process it further there.

However, I have a few problems,
one I do not know where to start and How the JSON files are constructed...its kind of mess. The JSONS were actually maded based on two API Get Request. One Api Get Request request the Points and the second one requests the details of the points. See this question here for some more context:
[API Request within another API request (Same API) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152751/api-request-within-another-api-request-same-api-in-python/66153040?noredirect=1#comment116958447_66153040)

Note because of character limit I cannot post the code here:

These details are of course supposed to be "the contours" of the area surrounding these points.
The thing is..the point itself is mentioned in the JSON, making it kind of hard to specify what coordinate is for each point. Not to mention all other attributes that are intresting to us, are in the "point" part of the GeoJSON.

Take a look at the JSON itself to see what I mean:

```
{
    "comment": null,
    "contactDetails": {
        "city": null,
        "country": "BE",
        "email": null,
        "extraAddressInfo": null,
        "firstName": null,
        "kboNumber": null,
        "lastName": "TMVW",
        "number": null,
        "organisation": "TMVW - Brugge-Kust",
        "phoneNumber1": null,
        "phoneNumber2": null,
        "postalCode": null,
        "street": null
    },
    "contractor": null,
    "description": "WEGENISWERKEN - Oostende - 154-W - H Baelskaai-project Oosteroever",
    "diversions": [],
    "endDateTime": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
    "gipodId": 1042078,
    "hindrance": {
        "description": null,
        "direction": null,
        "effects": [
            "Omleiding: beide richtingen",
            "Afgesloten: volledige rijweg",
            "Fietsers hebben geen doorgang",
            "Handelaars bereikbaar",
            "Plaatselijk verkeer: toegelaten",
            "Voetgangers hebben doorgang"
        ],
        "important": true,
        "locations": [
            "Voetpad",
            "Fietspad",
            "Parkeerstrook",
            "Rijbaan"
        ]
    },
    "latestUpdate": "2020-12-01T12:16:00.03",
    "location": {
        "cities": [
            "Oostende"
        ],
        "coordinate": {
            "coordinates": [
                2.931988215468502,
                51.23633810341717
            ],
            "crs": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
                },
                "type": "name"
            },
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        2.932567101705748,
                        51.23657315009855
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9309934586397337,
                        51.235776874431004
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9328606392338914,
                        51.2345112414401
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9344086040607285,
                        51.23535468563417
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9344709862243095,
                        51.23529463700852
                    ],
                    [
                        2.932928489694045,
                        51.23447026126373
                    ],
                    [
                        2.935453674897618,
                        51.2326691257775
                    ],
                    [
                        2.937014893295095,
                        51.23347469462423
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9370649363167556,
                        51.23342209549579
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9355339718818847,
                        51.23261689467634
                    ],
                    [
                        2.937705787093551,
                        51.23108125372614
                    ],
                    [
                        2.939235922008332,
                        51.23191301940206
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9393162149112086,
                        51.231860784836144
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9377921292631313,
                        51.23102909334536
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9395494398210404,
                        51.22978103014327
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9395326861153492,
                        51.22973522407282
                    ],
                    [
                        2.9307116955342982,
                        51.23588365892173
                    ],
                    [
                        2.93077732400986,
                        51.235914858980586
                    ],
                    [
                        2.930921969180147,
                        51.23581685905391
                    ],
                    [
                        2.932475593354336,
                        51.23662429379119
                    ],
                    [
                        2.932567101705748,
                        51.23657315009855
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "crs": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
                },
                "type": "name"
            },
            "type": "Polygon"
        }
    },
    "mainContractor": null,
    "owner": "TMVW - Brugge-Kust",
    "reference": "DOM-154/15/004-W",
    "startDateTime": "2017-05-02T00:00:00",
    "state": "In uitvoering",
    "type": "Wegeniswerken (her)aanleg",
    "url": null
}
```

As a reminder these JSON's are not supposed to be point files and the geometry can be either a polygon as seen above: A multipolygon or a multiLinestring (do not have an example here).

**So how do I get started and make sure I not only get the detail attributes out but clearly the contour geometry and coordinates?**

The only Unique id is the GIPOD ID, because this one is where the actual link in this API database is.

Edit 1:

So this is the supposed geojson standard.

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

Based on this standard, the converted JSON should be this:

```
    "type": "Feature",
               "geometry": {
                   "type": "Polygon",
                   "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            2.932567101705748,
                            51.23657315009855
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9309934586397337,
                            51.235776874431004
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9328606392338914,
                            51.2345112414401
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9344086040607285,
                            51.23535468563417
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9344709862243095,
                            51.23529463700852
                        ],
                        [
                            2.932928489694045,
                            51.23447026126373
                        ],
                        [
                            2.935453674897618,
                            51.2326691257775
                        ],
                        [
                            2.937014893295095,
                            51.23347469462423
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9370649363167556,
                            51.23342209549579
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9355339718818847,
                            51.23261689467634
                        ],
                        [
                            2.937705787093551,
                            51.23108125372614
                        ],
                        [
                            2.939235922008332,
                            51.23191301940206
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9393162149112086,
                            51.231860784836144
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9377921292631313,
                            51.23102909334536
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9395494398210404,
                            51.22978103014327
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9395326861153492,
                            51.22973522407282
                        ],
                        [
                            2.9307116955342982,
                            51.23588365892173
                        ],
                        [
                            2.93077732400986,
                            51.235914858980586
                        ],
                        [
                            2.930921969180147,
                            51.23581685905391
                        ],
                        [
                            2.932475593354336,
                            51.23662429379119
                        ],
                        [
                            2.932567101705748,
                            51.23657315009855
                        ]
                   ]
               },
               "properties": {
Too much columns to type, cannot claim them all here because of character limit.
                   }
           }
```

Edit 3: The Solution provided was a good step in the right direction but it gives me two problems:

1. The saved geometry is Null making this JSON a table without
   geometry.
2. Only 1 data_point is saved and not all data_points that are
   being requested.

Here is the JSON:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"gipodId": 3099549, "StartDateTime": null, "EndDateTime": null, "state": null, "location": {"cities": ["Waregem", "Wielsbeke"], "coordinate": {"coordinates": [3.4206971887218445, 50.91662742195287], "type": "Point", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}}}}]}
```

Python Code: Below to see how far it has gone:

```
import requests
import json
import os
import glob
import shutil

def process_location_data(location_json): 
   """Converts the data point into required geojson format"""

  
   # assigning variable to store geometry details
   geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometery")
   #geometery_details.pop("crs")  # removes the "crs" from geometry

   # includes city and location_coordinates
   location_details = {
     "cities": location_json.get("location").get("cities"),
     "coordinate": location_json.get("location").get("coordinate")
   }

   #EndDateTime
   end_datetime = location_json.get("EndDateTime")

   #StarDateTime
   start_datetime = location_json.get("StarDateTime")

   #State
   state = location_json.get("State")

   #gipodId
   gipod_id = location_json.get("gipodId")
   
   #adding all these details into another dict
   properties = {
     "gipodId": gipod_id,
     "StartDateTime": start_datetime,
     "EndDateTime": end_datetime,
     "state": state,
     "location": location_details
   }


   # creating the final dict to be returned.
   geojson_data_point = {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry" : geometery_details,
       "properties": properties
   }

   return geojson_data_point

def process_all_location_data(all_location_points):
    """
    For all the points in the location details we will  
    create the feature collection
    """

    feature_collection = {
         "type": "FeatureCollection",
         "features": []
    } #creates dict with zero features.

    for data_point in all_location_points:
        feature_collection.get("features").append(
            process_location_data(data_point)
        )

    return feature_collection


def fetch_details(url: str, file_name: str):
      # Makes request call to get the data of detail
        response = requests.get(url)
        print("Sending Request for details of gpodId: " + file_name)
        folder_path ='api_request_jsons/fetch_details/JSON unfiltered'
        text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=False, indent=4)
        print("Details extracted for: "+ file_name)
        save_file(folder_path,file_name,text)
        return response.json()
        # save_file(folder_path,GipodId,text2)
        # any other processe

def fetch_points(url: str):
       response = requests.get(url)
       folder_path ='api_request_jsons/fetch_points'
       text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=False, indent=4)
       print("Points Fetched, going to next step: Extracting details")
       for obj in response.json():
         all_location_points = [fetch_details(obj.get("detail"),str(obj.get("gipodId")))]
       save_file(folder_path,'points',text)
       feature_collection_json = process_all_location_data(all_location_points)
       text2 = json.dumps(process_all_location_data(all_location_points))
       folder_path2 = "api_request_jsons/fetch_details/Coordinates"
       file_name2 = "Converted"
       save_file(folder_path2,file_name2,text2)
       return feature_collection_json

def save_file(save_path: str, file_name: str, file_information: str):
        completeName = os.path.join(save_path, file_name +".json")
        print(completeName + " saved")
        file1 = open(completeName, "wt")
        file1.write(file_information)
        file1.close()

api_response_url = "http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment"
fetch_points(api_response_url)
```

Comment: Hi Joerie, let me try to understand the challenge. Here you want to extract only the location key form json for each data point, or just the geometry of the location?

Comment: Location and geometry if possible, not to mention also the other attributes to translate later on in QGIS. It just needs to be readable in QGIS (converted in GeoJSON) including with the other attributes and properties. If that is too hard maybe split the non location date up in seperate CSV files and join them later on by the Unique GIPODID.

Best scenerio, Location coordinates, gemeotry, StarDateTime, EndDateTime and State. Resulting in GeoJSON.

Comment: Location coordinates and geometry in different feature collection or same? I am not experienced with geo json. Can you share a sample of expected outcome. I will able to help more effectively if I have that for reference.

Comment: As I have stated before the gemeotry and location of the Polygon/MultiPolygon/MultiString. A moment creating an example for how it "should look". Based on the Geojson standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on #Edit 3 of the question, I have updated the complete solution. There are two issues.

- Typo in function `process_location_data`. In this function, I was loading `geometery` instead of `geometry` (check the typo in spelling)

```
       # incorrect for code
       geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometery")
    
       # correct one
       geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometry")
```

Also, I found typos in `state`, `endDateTime` and `startDateTime` keys of the object. (fixed in the complete solution provided below)

- Appending the list `all_location_points` in the `fetch_points` function.

```
    #Current code
    for obj in response.json():                                                                                               
        all_location_points = [                                                                                               
            fetch_details(obj.get("detail"), str(obj.get("gipodId")))                                                            
        ]
```

In this `all_location_points` is getting updated each time with the `obj`, instead of appending it to the list.

```
# Fixed 

    all_location_points = []                                                                                                  
    for obj in response.json():                                                                                               
        all_location_points.append(                                                                                           
            fetch_details(obj.get("detail"), str(obj.get("gipodId")))                                                            
        )
```

In the above answer, I had used shorthand for creating a list (list comprehension). the above 3 lines could be converted into a single line as

```
    all_location_points = [
      fetch_details(obj.get("detail"), str(obj.get("gipodId")))
      for obj in response.json()
    ]
```

The complete updated solution,  (including typo fix and appending list)

```
    import requests
    import json
    import os
    import glob
    import shutil
    
    
    def process_location_data(location_json):
        """Converts the data point into required geojson format"""
    
        # assigning variable to store geometry details
        geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometry")
        # geometery_details.pop("crs")  # removes the "crs" from geometry
    
        # includes city and location_coordinates
        location_details = {
            "cities": location_json.get("location").get("cities"),
            "coordinate": location_json.get("location").get("coordinate"),
        }
    
        # EndDateTime
        end_datetime = location_json.get("endDateTime")
    
        # StarDateTime
        start_datetime = location_json.get("startDateTime")
    
        # State
        state = location_json.get("state")
    
        # gipodId
        gipod_id = location_json.get("gipodId")
    
        # adding all these details into another dict
        properties = {
            "gipodId": gipod_id,
            "StartDateTime": start_datetime,
            "EndDateTime": end_datetime,
            "state": state,
            "location": location_details,
        }
    
        # creating the final dict to be returned.
        geojson_data_point = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": geometery_details,
            "properties": properties,
        }
    
        return geojson_data_point
    
    
    def process_all_location_data(all_location_points):
        """
        For all the points in the location details we will
        create the feature collection
        """
    
        feature_collection = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [],
        }  # creates dict with zero features.
    
        for data_point in all_location_points:
            feature_collection.get("features").append(process_location_data(data_point))
    
        return feature_collection
    
    
    def fetch_details(url: str, file_name: str):
        # Makes request call to get the data of detail
        response = requests.get(url)
        print("Sending Request for details of gpodId: " + file_name)
        folder_path = "api_request_jsons/fetch_details/JSON unfiltered"
        text = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
        print("Details extracted for: " + file_name)
        save_file(folder_path, file_name, text)
        return response.json()
        # save_file(folder_path,GipodId,text2)
        # any other processe
    
    
    def fetch_points(url: str):
        response = requests.get(url)
        folder_path = "api_request_jsons/fetch_points"
        text = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
        print("Points Fetched, going to next step: Extracting details")
        all_location_points = []
        for obj in response.json():
            all_location_points.append(
                fetch_details(obj.get("detail"), str(obj.get("gipodId")))
            )
        save_file(folder_path, "points", text)
        feature_collection_json = process_all_location_data(all_location_points)
        text2 = json.dumps(process_all_location_data(all_location_points))
        folder_path2 = "api_request_jsons/fetch_details/Coordinates"
        file_name2 = "Converted"
        save_file(folder_path2, file_name2, text2)
        return feature_collection_json
    
    
    def save_file(save_path: str, file_name: str, file_information: str):
        completeName = os.path.join(save_path, file_name + ".json")
        print(completeName + " saved")
        file1 = open(completeName, "wt")
        file1.write(file_information)
        file1.close()
    
    
    api_response_url = "http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment"
    fetch_points(api_response_url)
```

Comment: Okay now everything works fine but the thing is QGIS, still refuses it to load it correctly. It still a table with no geometry and only one object.

I think I know what the problem is, but I will need to ask in another forum to confirm it because this is a GIS related subject.

Comment: Share the error which you are getting. Maybe I might be able to assist you with that

Comment: There is not really an error but I can give you some screenshots to show what I mean. The Data just does not really seem to be the correct format for it to load the way it should be. Give me 10 mins.

Comment: I have found the Sollution to my problem...Apparantly I needed to introduce and Indent = 4 . Into my JSON dump and then it was recognized one thing though nice code, but considering the other properties I am missing. I may need to expand this code. Thank you. Also Need to add some checks later on. Because I need to check if the Features amount of features are correct, I can easily check that in the loop. Thank you once again.

Comment: That's good to know that you found the solution. We are hear to help each other. Feel free to ask any futher queries

Answer (score 1):

You can create another function and pass the data to it.

```
# assuming you got the list of points
# and it's stored in all_location_points 

def process_location_data(location_json): 
   """Converts the data point into required geojson format"""
  
   # assigning variable to store geometry details
   geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometery")
   geometery_details.pop("crs")  # removes the "crs" from geometry

   # includes city and location_coordinates
   location_details = {
     "cities": location_json.get("location").get("cities"),
     "coordinate": location_json.get("location").get("coordinate")
   }

   #EndDateTime
   end_datetime = location_json.get("EndDateTime")

   #StarDateTime
   start_datetime = location_json.get("StarDateTime")

   #State
   state = location_json.get("State")

   #gipodId
   gipood_id = location_json.get("gipodId")
   
   #adding all these details into another dict
   properties = {
     "gipodId": gipood_id,
     "StartDateTime": start_datetime,
     "EndDateTime": end_datetime,
     "state": state,
     "location": location_details
   }


   # creating the final dict to be returned.
   geojson_data_point = {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry" : geometery_details,
       "properties": properties
   } 

   return geojson_data_point


def process_all_location_data(all_location_points):
    """
    For all the points in the location details we will  
    create the feature collection
    """

    feature_collection = {
         "type": "FeatureCollection",
         "features": []
    } #creates dict with zero features.

    for data_point in all_location_points:
        feature_collection.get("features").append(
            process_location_data(data_point)
        )

    return feature_collection
```

Referring to [API Request within another API request (Same API) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152751/api-request-within-another-api-request-same-api-in-python/66153040?noredirect=1#comment116958447_66153040), you can use this function as

```
def fetch_details(url: str):
      """
      Makes request call to get the data of detail
     (updated to return details)
      """
      response = requests.get(url)
      return response.json()
       

def fetch_points(url: str):
     """
     Updating this function to fetch and process all points
     and convert them to json
     """
      
       
     response = requests.get(url)
     # shot hand to create list of all the detail points
     all_location_points = [
        fetch_details(obj.get("detail")) for obj in response.json()
     ]

     feature_collection_json = process_all_location_data(all_location_points)
     return feature_colkection_json

api_url = "api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment"
fetch_points(api_url)
```

Edit 4: While the JSON is finnaly converted to something that seems to be close to the GeoJSON standard RFC 7946.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946

There should be one thing you should do to convert it to something QGIS can read.

Comment: I sadly get an error arround the
all_location_points = [fetch_details(obj.get("detail")) for obj in resonse.json()]
part the thing is Repl.It does not show me what the error is, It just being highlihgted that this is the problem.

Comment: Never mind that last part I can confirm the Code works with some modifications, while this setup is great it is gonna be bit hard for me to figure out how to save these GeoJSON in Separate files.Which will be a separate question.

Comment: Your code is great but I got few new problems see my last Edit please.

Comment: Damm. Yes, I saw the issues. Mostly thanks to my typos. I am adding a new answer with a complete solution.