# Python: Saving GeoJSON after convertion from JSON as a JSON/GeoJSON

Tags: python, json, geojson

Note this Question is a continuation of this:

[Converting JSON to QGIS GeoJSON: while having multiple features and different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170590/converting-json-to-qgis-geojson-while-having-multiple-features-and-different-ty/66184842#66184842)

After some help I managed to convert some JSON to GeoJSON that should be readable in QGIS. The thing is the functions are made I still need to save the files to test them.

The thing is While I know how to save JSON files even making a special function for it, I do not how to save this JSON files altered, currently I am saving these JSON files unaltered but now I want to save them altered.

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import glob
import shutil

# response = requests.get("http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment", params = {"CRS": "Lambert72"})

# text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=True, indent=4)
# print(text)

# f = open("text.json", "wt")
# f.write(text)
# print(response.status_code)


def process_location_data(location_json):
    """Converts the data point into required geojson format"""

    # assigning variable to store geometry details
    geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometery")
    # geometery_details.pop("crs")  # removes the "crs" from geometry

    # includes city and location_coordinates
    location_details = {
        "cities": location_json.get("location").get("cities"),
        "coordinate": location_json.get("location").get("coordinate")
    }

    # EndDateTime
    end_datetime = location_json.get("EndDateTime")

    # StarDateTime
    start_datetime = location_json.get("StarDateTime")

    # State
    state = location_json.get("State")

    # gipodId
    gipod_id = location_json.get("gipodId")

    # adding all these details into another dict
    properties = {
        "gipodId": gipod_id,
        "StartDateTime": start_datetime,
        "EndDateTime": end_datetime,
        "state": state,
        "location": location_details
    }

    # creating the final dict to be returned.
    geojson_data_point = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": geometery_details,
        "properties": properties
    }

    return geojson_data_point


def process_all_location_data(all_location_points):
    """
    For all the points in the location details we will  
    create the feature collection
    """

    feature_collection = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
    }  # creates dict with zero features.

    for data_point in all_location_points:
        feature_collection.get("features").append(
            process_location_data(data_point)
        )

    return feature_collection


def fetch_details(url: str, file_name: str):
    # Makes request call to get the data of detail
    response = requests.get(url)
    folder_path = 'api_request_jsons/fetch_details/JSON unfiltered'
    text = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
    print(text)
    save_file(folder_path, file_name, text)
    return response.json()

    # save_file(folder_path,GipodId,text2)

    # any other processe


def fetch_points(url: str):
    response = requests.get(url)
    folder_path = 'api_request_jsons/fetch_points'
    text = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
    print("Points Fetched, going to next step")
    i = 1
    for obj in response.json():
        # Printing object id for confirmation
        print("fetching object detais from gipodId " + str(obj.get("gipodId")))
        file_name = str(obj.get("gipodId"))
        # Getting the object details
        all_location_points = [fetch_details(obj.get("detail"), file_name)]
    save_file(folder_path, 'points', text)
    feature_collection_json = process_all_location_data(all_location_points)
    return feature_collection_json
    print(feature_collection_json)
    # text2 = text[int('coordinate')]
    # print(text2)


def save_file(save_path: str, file_name: str, file_information: str):
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, file_name + ".json")
    print(completeName)
    file1 = open(completeName, "wt")
    file1.write(file_information)
    file1.close()


api_response_url = "http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment"
fetch_points(api_response_url)
```

So how do I do this with save_file function I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kind of found the answer to my question I am posting the code here below. It was kind of obvious how I should have done it but it was kind of mess to see where I have should put my save command.

```
import requests
import json
import os
import glob
import shutil

def process_location_data(location_json): 
   """Converts the data point into required geojson format"""

  
   # assigning variable to store geometry details
   geometery_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometery")
   #geometery_details.pop("crs")  # removes the "crs" from geometry

   # includes city and location_coordinates
   location_details = {
     "cities": location_json.get("location").get("cities"),
     "coordinate": location_json.get("location").get("coordinate")
   }

   #EndDateTime
   end_datetime = location_json.get("EndDateTime")

   #StarDateTime
   start_datetime = location_json.get("StarDateTime")

   #State
   state = location_json.get("State")

   #gipodId
   gipod_id = location_json.get("gipodId")
   
   #adding all these details into another dict
   properties = {
     "gipodId": gipod_id,
     "StartDateTime": start_datetime,
     "EndDateTime": end_datetime,
     "state": state,
     "location": location_details
   }


   # creating the final dict to be returned.
   geojson_data_point = {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry" : geometery_details,
       "properties": properties
   }

   return geojson_data_point

def process_all_location_data(all_location_points):
    """
    For all the points in the location details we will  
    create the feature collection
    """

    feature_collection = {
         "type": "FeatureCollection",
         "features": []
    } #creates dict with zero features.

    for data_point in all_location_points:
        feature_collection.get("features").append(
            process_location_data(data_point)
        )

    return feature_collection


def fetch_details(url: str, file_name: str):
      # Makes request call to get the data of detail
        response = requests.get(url)
        print("Sending Request for details of gpodId: " + file_name)
        folder_path ='api_request_jsons/fetch_details/JSON unfiltered'
        text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=False, indent=4)
        print("Details extracted for: "+ file_name)
        save_file(folder_path,file_name,text)
        return response.json()
        # save_file(folder_path,GipodId,text2)
        # any other processe

def fetch_points(url: str):
       response = requests.get(url)
       folder_path ='api_request_jsons/fetch_points'
       text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=False, indent=4)
       print("Points Fetched, going to next step: Extracting details")
       for obj in response.json():
         all_location_points = [fetch_details(obj.get("detail"),str(obj.get("gipodId")))]
       save_file(folder_path,'points',text)
       feature_collection_json = process_all_location_data(all_location_points)
       text2 = json.dumps(process_all_location_data(all_location_points))
       folder_path2 = "api_request_jsons/fetch_details/Coordinates"
       file_name2 = "Converted"
       save_file(folder_path2,file_name2,text2)
       return feature_collection_json

def save_file(save_path: str, file_name: str, file_information: str):
        completeName = os.path.join(save_path, file_name +".json")
        print(completeName + " saved")
        file1 = open(completeName, "wt")
        file1.write(file_information)
        file1.close()

api_response_url = "http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment"
fetch_points(api_response_url)
```

But now after testing the Converted JSON file in QGIS I have found that these JSON returns as GeoJSON without geometry. I have other problems,  but you can find that in the previous topic.